# UICollectionView - register Nib only if needed

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I try to create some universal extensions for `UITableView` and `UICollectionView` to reduce boiler code needed to work with collections.

For `UITableView` I have this:

```
extension UITableView {

    public func dequeueReusableCell<T:UITableViewCell>(type: T.Type) -> T {
        let tableCell       : T
        let cellIdentifier  = String(T)

        if let cell = self.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as? T {
            tableCell = cell
        } else if let _ = NSBundle(forClass: T.classForCoder()).pathForResource(cellIdentifier, ofType:"nib") {
            self.registerNib(UINib(nibName: cellIdentifier, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
            if let cell = NSBundle(forClass: T.classForCoder()).loadNibNamed(cellIdentifier, owner: nil, options: nil)[0] as? T {
                tableCell = cell
            } else {
                //if anyone had better suggestion for fallback, you're welcome to comment
                tableCell = T(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
            }
        } else {
            tableCell = T(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
        }
        return tableCell
    }
}
```

For `UICollectionView` currently I only have this:

```
extension UICollectionView {

    public func dequeueReusableCell<T:UICollectionViewCell>(type: T.Type, indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> T {
        let collectionCell  : T
        let cellIdentifier  = String(T)

        if let _ = NSBundle(forClass: T.classForCoder()).pathForResource(cellIdentifier, ofType:"nib") {
            self.registerNib(UINib(nibName: cellIdentifier, bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
            collectionCell = self.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! T
        }
        else {
            collectionCell = T()
        }
        return collectionCell

    }
}
```

Which works but I don't think it's *neat* enough. What I would like to improve is to call `registerNib` only once. Unfortunately, I can't call `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` because it will fail on internal assertion. I've tried to play with **try catch** mechanism in Swift but to no avail.

Any suggestion?

I know I can just register **nib** once in VC, but that's not a point of having these categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need a way to associate information about nib registration state with a NIB with certain name. Unfortunately, you create UINib instance again each time, so this flag can't be associated with UINib instance. For example, add a static dictionary with a mapping of identifiers to flags to the extension of UINib (as a property via associated objects, for instance). Or create UINib subclass, it would be even better. Set this flag first time you register a NIB. Check this flag next times.

**EDIT**: there is a great talk [AdvancedCollectionView: Advanced User Interfaces Using Collection View](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014-232/)  presented on WWDC 2014. Source code is available [here](https://developer.apple.com/sample-code/wwdc/2015/downloads/Advanced-Collection-View.zip). There is a class AAPLShadowRegistrar which does exactly what you need: maintains a registry for reusable views and NIBs.

Comment: Not good enough if you are using multiple cell types in one `UICollectionView`. Would need to store dumb array, there must be more neat way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sample code that you can use. The idea is to pass an array of alreadyRegistered nib names which is populated whenever you register your xib. You can use this in your code and from where you call you just have to pass an array. This could be a global array.

You just have to call this at the beginning of your function passing the name of the cell Id and the global array.

```
extension ViewController
{
    func registerNibName(name:String, inout alreadyRegistered:[String])
    {
        if !alreadyRegistered.contains(name) {
            alreadyRegistered.append(name)
            //self.registerNib(name)
            print("registerNib with name \(name)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Again, I shouldn't assume that there are fixed numbers of UICollectionViewCell` types used in `UICollectionView`, so this is not enough for me.

Comment: I have updated the answer a bit. Please refer and see if this works for you. Note that  I have used a sample and not your actual class but I am sure you get the idea.